# How can I make variables to send different e-mail messages?

Tags: php

I have different forms on my website that send me emails. Each of those forms has its own separate .php file so I thought it would be a good idea if I had just one single php file that sent out the email to me.

The way I plan doing this is having hidden inputs on my forms that have a unique id. The php picks up that id and depending on what the id equals the php will send a different email to me.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php
$to .= 'myemailadress@mydomain.com';

$feedback_page = "feedback.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

$form_id = $_REQUEST['form_id'] ; /* This is what will determine the email message */

$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ; /*This is what picks up what the person wrote */
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$email_adress = $_REQUEST['emai_address'];

if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

elseif (empty($email_adress)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

else {
    $mailmsg = "
    Name: $first_name $last_name
    Email: $email_address
    ";

$headers .= 'From: forms@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: otheremail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";

mail( "$to", $form_name , $mailmsg , $headers );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

What can I add to this code that will change the email message it sends depending on that ID input I mentioned?

While I was typing in the code I thought that one possible way of doing this would be setting different email messages like $mailmsg1 or $mailmsg2 and inside of the  mail() put in some variables that determine what mail message is sent. Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement it with a PHP `switch` statement that sets the `$mailmsg` accordingly.  Something like this (untested):

```
switch ($form_id) {
    case "1":
        $mailmsg="Something"; // Message 1
        break;
    case "2":
        $mailmsg="Something else"; // Message 2
        break;
    default:
        $mailmsg="Default message";
        break;
```

Also, just a heads up you may have a typo in the Request below:

```
$email_adress = $_REQUEST['emai_address'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic change you could make would be to put an `if..else` in the part that sets the message body text and test the `$form_id` for the form ids you've set in your hidden input elements.

I've only included the last part here:

```
// ... first part of the code ommited
else
{
   if($form_id === SOME_ID_1)
   {
        // set here the message for form id 1

        $mailmsg = "
            Name: $first_name $last_name
            Email: $email_address
        ";
   }else if($form_id === SOME_ID_2)
   {
        // set here the message for form id 2
        $mailmsg = "
           ... WHATEVER MESSAGE YOU'D LIKE FOR FORM 2
        ";
   }else{
        // set here a default message if you want or redirect to error page

   }

   $headers .= 'From: forms@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Bcc: otheremail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";

   mail( "$to", $form_name , $mailmsg , $headers );
   header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
```

But probably a much nicer abstraction would be to actually move all that code that you use to send an e-mail into a function and just call that with different messages and or subjects depending on the `$form_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a switch case statement which chooses the correct emailaddress to send to:

```
$mailMessage = "";
switch ($form_id) {
    case 0:
        $mailMessage += "Hello Son,";
        $mailMessage += "Goodbye";
        break;
    case 1:
        //Same here as above
        break;
    case 2:
        //Same here as case 0
        break;
}

mail( "$to", $form_name , $mailMessage, $headers );
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood what I meant but what I need to change is the message that is sent not the email it is sent too, but I understand the idea behind what you mentioned so I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot cleaner to just post back to your same form, validating the form and generating the message there.  From that point you can send the message to whatever email handling script you decide to use.

Comment: I realize that's not answering the exact question you had, but its certainly the way to go.